# Javascript API Queue in forEach loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, loops, queue

**Summary of Objective**

I need to implement an API queue in my Node.js backend for API calls.  The API rate limit I need to adhear to is 1 request every 2 seconds and it's a hard limit.  I'm making my API call inside of a forEach loop since I need to do one API call for each user.

I've found a lot of articles online about how to create a queue but they mostly involve adding API calls to an array so I'm not sure how to implement a queue in this situation.

Any help would be greatly apprecaited and I can share more code if it's help.

**Code**

```
async function refreshStats() {
  try {
    // get list of all fortnite users
    const fnUserList = await Users.find({}, "_id fnUserPlatform"); // my fnUser _id 5cca01ea8f52f40117b2ff51
    fnUserList.forEach(async fnUser => {
      //make  API call.  apiCall is a function I created to make the API call and format the response
      const { lifeStats, statsEqual } = await apiCall(
        fnUser.fnUserPlatform
      );
      //execute other functions with apiCall response
    });
  } catch (err) {
    console.error("error in refreshStats", err);
  }
}
```

Comment: You could use [RateLimiterQueue](https://github.com/animir/node-rate-limiter-flexible/wiki/RateLimiterQueue) from [rate-limiter-flexible](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rate-limiter-flexible) package.

Answer (score 0):

If i get it correctly. You can take advantage of `generator functions` and combine it with `setInterval`. You can make make a queue function that enqueues its items in specified intervals.

> Create a generator function basically makes an apiCall and pauses

```js
    async function* queueGenerator(userList) {
        for (let fnUser of userList) {
            const result = {lifeStats, statsEqual} = await apiCall(fnUser.fnUserPlatform);      
            yield result;
        }
    }
```

> Then in your method create a queue and enqueue items with setInterval

```
    async function refreshStats() {
        try {
            // get list of all fortnite users
            let handle;
            const fnUserList = await Users.find({}, "_id fnUserPlatform"); // my fnUser _id 5cca01ea8f52f40117b2ff51
            const queue = queueGenerator(fnUserList);
            const results = [];
            handle = setInterval(async () => {
                const result = await queue.next();
                results.push(result.value);
                if (results.length === users.length) clearInterval(handle);
            }, 2000);

        } catch (err) {
            console.error("error in refreshStats", err);
        }
    }
```

Also there is another way which is to use `setTimeout` combined with `Promise`s. which involves creating promises that resolves in setTimeOut with enough of delays.

```js
async function refreshStatsV2() {
  const fnUserList = await Users.find({}, "_id fnUserPlatform");
  const promises = fnUserList.map((fnUser, ix) => (
    new Promise(resolve =>
      setTimeout(async() => {
        const result = {
          lifeStats,
          statsEqual
        } = await apiCall(ix.fnUserPlatform);
        resolve(result);
      }, ix * 2000) // delay every next item 2sec
    )));

  const result = await Promise.all(promises); // wait all
  console.log(result);
}
```